# How to define a class variable on a singleton class

Tags: ruby, singleton, class-variables

I want to define a class variable on a singleton class. I checked this program's result:

```
class C
  class << self
    @@val = 100
  end
end

C.singleton_class.class_variables #=> [], I expect [:@@val]
C.class_variables #=> [:@@val]
```

I expect the scope of `@@val` to be the singleton class, isn't it?

Would you tell me how to define a class variable on a singleton class using `class << self`, and the reason why this program is not correct?

Answer (score 3):

It is because when Ruby parser meets a class variable, the current class is resolved according to the lexical scope.

Cf. http://blog.honeybadger.io/lexical-scoping-and-ruby-class-variables/

Answer (score 1):

To set the singleton class variable, one might use:

```
class C
  class << self
    class_variable_set :@@cv, 42
  end
end
C.singleton_class.class_variables #⇒ [:@@cv]
C.singleton_class.class_variable_get :@@cv #⇒ 42
```

Comment: thanks. would you tell me why above program is not correct?. that scope is singleton class, isn't it ?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I am convinced this is ruby parser glitch. The scope is `C.singleton_class`, yes. Even `class C ; class << self ; class << self ; @@ccv = 42 ; end ; end ; end` results in setting class variable on `C`. Probably this is how `@` and `@@` are handled. It responds to the class opened despite whether it appears inside class method, instance method, or any declaration.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I have it on purpose.