# How to define class variables for Singleton instance of a Ruby class?

Tags: ruby

How do we define a class variable for a singleton instance of a class?

Where exactly will the class variable be put for Ruby? What does the location of the class variables depend on? Scope, Lexical context or the current class?

```
class C
    class << self
        @@c = 1
    end
end
# C.class_variables => [:@@a]
# Why the class variables belong to C, instead of singleton instance of C?

class D
end
class << D
    @@d = 1
end
# Object.class_variables => [:@@d]
# warning: class variable access from toplevel
# Why the class variables belong to Object, instead of class D or singleton class of class D?

# How Ruby decide why to put the class variables?
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921185/how-to-define-a-class-variable-on-a-singleton-class

Comment: It's [recommended to avoid](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-class-vars) the usage of class variables due to their "nasty" behavior in inheritance

Comment: @mechnicov Yeah, I know that we should avoid using class variables when actually programming, but I just what to know about it. I think the lexical scope in ruby is quite complex, as I used java before...

Comment: @cremno I have read this before, but what confuses me is that class << D will change the hexical scope that current class is the singleton class of D, so why can't we just simply put a class variable in the singleton class of D, without using method class_variable_set? This is the inner design of Ruby to protect us from using too much class variables? haha

Comment: Your title refers to "singleton instance of a Ruby class". That's not clear. Classes don't have singleton instances and singleton classes don't have instances (`Class.new.singleton_class.new #=>  TypeError (can't create instance of singleton class)`.

Answer (score 0):

For a class `C`, it appears that defining a class variable on `C`'s singleton class is equivalent to defining the same class variable on `C`.

```
class C
  @@a = 0
  class << self
    @@c = 1
  end
end

class D < C
end
```

```
C.class_variables
  #=> [:@@a, :@@c] 
D.class_variables
  #=> [:@@a, :@@c] 
C.singleton_class.class_variables
  #=> [] 
D.singleton_class.class_variables
  #=> []
```

```
D.class_variable_get(:@@a)
  #=> 0 
D.class_variable_set(:@@a, 2)
  #=> 2 
D.class_variables
  #=> [:@@a, :@@c] 
C.class_variable_get(:@@a)
  #=> 2
```

```
D.singleton_class.class_variable_get(:@@c)
  #=> 1 
D.singleton_class.class_variable_set(:@@c, 3)
  #=> 3 
C.singleton_class.class_variable_get(:@@c)
  #=> 3
```

Comment: Yeah, I try an demo like I use class to open a class, than use several class << to open the singleton class of the singleton class of... of the class, even if I have use servel class <<, if I want to define a class variable, it define as the class variable of the class itself, instead of the singleton class. The only way is to use a method: class_variable_set. Thank you so much.